# How to get the value of a selectize input

Tags: selectize.js

What's the cleanest way to get the values from a selectize input for submission via AJAX or a normal form?

I would like to see the equivalent of:

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for single selectize (haven't tried with multiple)

```
var myFieldValue;

$('#myField').selectize({
   ...
   onChange : function(id){
      myFieldValue = id;
      //alternatively, to get the text value use the following:
      myFieldValue = this.options[id];
   } 
});
```